# How to integrate karate-gatling with Grafana & influxdb to monitor result online

Tags: karate, gatling

I'a using karate to run api testing and leveraging the same performance tests with karate-gatling, but currently I want to integrate grafana & influxdb to show report online

Comment: this is an unsolved problem at the moment, maybe you can contribute !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see if this thread on integrating Allure / Extent / ReportPortal gives you some hints:

https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/619

Comment: I found a simple solution for this, just add gatling.conf in resouces folder

Comment: @cuhavp would be great if you post details somewhere, maybe as an answer to your own question here (which is encouraged on stack overflow) - or blog post etc. I am sure this will be of interest to MANY folks !